# ActiveMQ: One Pending Message but Queue is empty

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, message-queue, wso2-esb

I have a strange problem with ActiveMQ. I have a queue that seems to have a pending message, but when I open the queue, there is no message.

What is wrong here? Is there really a message pending? How can I bring the message back or at least see the content?

Screenshot of the pending message:
[image]

Screenshot when opening the queue, which is empty:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Just found these two bugs of ActiveMQ 5.6.0. Can this be the source of that problem?

[Incorrect reporting of pendingQueueSize of durable subs after reconnect with unacked](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3998)

[Problem in OrderPendingList can lead to message not being deliver after durable sub reconnect.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I updated to ActiveMQ 5.7.0 quite some time ago and didn't had this bug anymore since. So I'd say my problem was due to these bugs here:

[Incorrect reporting of pendingQueueSize of durable subs after reconnect with unacked](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3998)

[Problem in OrderPendingList can lead to message not being deliver after durable sub reconnect.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3871)

Comment: It's strange because I still have that kind of issue with version 5.10.2 of ActiveMQ. Apparently there's a bug in the JMX counters but cannot see any reference on this.

Comment: Same here. Running 5.12.0 and I also have this bug. According to DB the messages are in the queue. So the error seems not the counter but the display of the content of the queue. With hawtio I have the same issue. @ruffp: Did you found a solution?

Comment: I reasked this question for newer ActiveMq and other details:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435610/activemq-one-pending-message-but-queue-is-empty-activemq-5-12-0