# ActiveMQ: One Pending Message but Queue is empty - ActiveMQ 5.12.0

Tags: java, activemq-classic, hawtio

I have the same issue as described here:
[ActiveMQ: One Pending Message but Queue is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470017/activemq-one-pending-message-but-queue-is-empty).

Active MQ shows pending messages for the queue but when I click it it's empty.
[image: Queue with pending message]
[image: empty queue]

- Further clients:

  - with hawtio - same behaviour
  - my java consumer

    - does not consume anything
    - after restart, continued to consume

We persist our messages not in default kaha db but in Oracle DB. I could see the pending messages in database in table ACTIVEMQ_MSGS.

After restart of activeMQ all clients worked as expected. In the administration console I could see the messages and the java consumer consumed the messages.

The mentioned exsiting issue was solved with an update to ActiveMQ 5.7.0.
I checked the activeMQ logs but I didn't found errors or warnings. Producer for the messages was also not changed.

Any idea why I experience these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved now.
I also asked in the active mq mailing list:
http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/One-Pending-Message-but-Queue-is-empty-ActiveMQ-5-12-0-td4715720.html.

- First of all we added this method call in our client:

  ```
  org.apache.camel.ConsumerTemplate.doneUoW(Exchange exchange)
  ```

  but it didn't solve the problem finally
- Furthermore we had load problems in active mq which weren't visible (healthStatus was "good" and jvm values looked also fine).

  - We had too many queues in activeMQ used for logging the old messages.
  - After deletion of them everything works fine now.